# How do I get name from a many-to-many field in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am pretty new to Django.
I have the following code :

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    name = models.ManytoManyField(ModelA)
    colour = models.CharField(max_lenght=30)

iob = ModelB.objects.filter(name=name)
```

Now, this works fine :

```
for i in iob:
    print i.colour
```

And I want to do something like :

```
for i in iob:
    print i.name
```

But it doesnt work for sure. It outputs like :

```
<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x30a2e50>
```

I want to print the value of name. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a many to many, you need to do:

```
for i in iob:
    print i.colour
    for obj_name in i.name.all()
        print obj_name.name
```

Comment: That isnt working. It gives an error : `AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: Sorry Just edited. I thought `iob` is an object. Not a queryset